# Hibernate: Get Parent for OneToMany-Child Entity Without Bidirectional Relation

Tags: hibernate, parent, parent-child

how can i check if an entity has a parent entity which maps this entity over **@OneToMany** annotation.
The mapping is unidirectional defined on the parent

```
@Entity
public class ParentEntity {

    ...

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private Collection<ChildEntity> childEntities;

    ...
```

Hibernate automagically creates a mapping table, or if used **@JoinColumn** a column with the parent-id in the child table.
When the child gets persisted, hibernate adds the corresponding parent id to the db-table.

I do not want to define a bidirectional relation since i do not need this "feature" in my application-logic and there are already loads of entities which would need a change. I just need the parent for replication issues. This means i have to export some data to another DB schema (has different table structure).

I use an interceptor to trigger the replication action in the **"onSave"** method defined by the **Interceptor interface**. If a parent gets a new child, there is just the persist action of the child triggering. I do not know the parent it belongs to.

I really appreciate any help!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found an answer to the problem without using queries.

The Interceptor interface of Hibernate defines three methods concerning collections.

If a collection on an entity (ParentEntity in this case) is changed one of the three methods is called:

```
public void onCollectionRecreate(Object collection, Serializable key)
        throws CallbackException {
}


public void onCollectionRemove(Object collection, Serializable key)
        throws CallbackException {
}

public void onCollectionUpdate(Object collection, Serializable key)
        throws CallbackException {
}
```

The object "collection" is then of a type **PersistenceBag** from which the "owner" can be read. That would be the parent in this case. Another hint: The second parameter of the methods is the hibernate key of the "owner". For my purpose i have got a configuration file which maps the Hibernate entities to the tables on the target system. In this configuration the parnent java class is defined.

Answer (score 3):

```
int count = session.createCriteria(Parent.class)
    .createCriteria("childEntities")
    .add(Restrictions.eq(childIdInQuestion))
    .setProjetction(Projections.rowCount())
    .uniqueResult();

Boolean hasParent = count > 0;
```

Comment: thanks, firo for your solution! indeed i can find out even the ID of my parent. a little drawback is, that i always have to execute a query. i think, using this on a central position like the entity-interceptor could slow down the system. what i was thinking about was getting this information through some hibernate-internals like the EntityPersister without causing additional query-traffic.

Comment: then lazyloaded reference to parent is the way to go. You want to know the parent from the child, don't you? checking `Boolean hasParent = child.parent != null` is the easiest way without extra traffic

Comment: There is no child.parent because i do not have and do not want to build a bidirectional relation (big system - means a lot of changes). It is a bit confusing, because i have to export it to a quite different data-structure. Nevertheless - i found a solution - have a look below. Thanks Firo!